# c# how to create combobox in particular datagrid cell

Tags: c#

i am creating employees leave management system . i have two form . in first form user send leave request to HR and in my second form one datagrid where showing all emp leave request status.status by default show Pending . i want when HR click in status cell then one combobox show where HR replace Pending request to Accept or Reject.
anyone please tell me how can do it's.

Comment: what have you done so far? Please show your code.

Comment: This should put you in right direction http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294.ASPX

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7307/ComboBox-in-a-DataGrid

Comment: i tried this but it's show combobox in all cell.i want particular selected cell.  dataGridView1_CellContentClick()
        {
            ComboBox combobox1 = new ComboBox();
            combobox1.Location = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Location;
            combobox1.SelectedValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
             combobox1.Show();
         }
        Form_Load()
 { 
  combobox1.Hide();
  dataGridView1.Controls.Add(combobox1);
 }

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with creating a Combobox control variable (for example `cmbTest`) in code and in InitCustomEdit event of the cell, assign that variable to the control

```
if (e.Column.Key == yourColumnName)
e.EditControl = cmbTest;
```